# Why is my modification indices output wrong?

Tags: r, indices, r-lavaan, cfadmin

I'm new to R. I've run the following model in lavaan:

```
model.e <-'
+ PT =~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7
+ EC =~ V8 + V9 + V10 + V11 + V12 + V13 + V14
+ PD =~ V15 + V16 + V17 + V18 + V19 + V20 + V21
+ PT ~~ 1*PT
+ EC ~~ 1*EC
+ PD ~~ 1*PD'
> fit.e <- cfa(model.e, data = empathy, std.lv = TRUE)
> summary(fit.e)
> mi <- modindices(fit.e)
```

Notice how PT corresponds to V1-V7, EC with V8-V14 and PD with V15-V21, however, in the modification indices output none of those factors corresponds with the appropriate observable variables. There is also no modification indices for correlations between PT, EC and PD (please see below). I see that the output starts with line 49. Is that the problem? Why am I getting wrong output?
Thank you!!
Maria

```
lhs op rhs     mi    epc sepc.lv sepc.all sepc.nox
49   PT =~  V8  7.826  0.245   0.245    0.259    0.259
50   PT =~  V9  3.296  0.213   0.213    0.169    0.169
51   PT =~ V10  0.117 -0.034  -0.034   -0.028   -0.028
52   PT =~ V11  0.014 -0.012  -0.012   -0.010   -0.010
53   PT =~ V12  1.809 -0.176  -0.176   -0.117   -0.117
54   PT =~ V13  0.474 -0.070  -0.070   -0.056   -0.056
55   PT =~ V14  0.265 -0.050  -0.050   -0.044   -0.044
56   PT =~ V15  8.738  0.376   0.376    0.236    0.236
57   PT =~ V16  1.586  0.156   0.156    0.094    0.094
58   PT =~ V17  8.805  0.296   0.296    0.206    0.206
59   PT =~ V18  4.554 -0.192  -0.192   -0.145   -0.145
60   PT =~ V19  0.287 -0.059  -0.059   -0.039   -0.039
61   PT =~ V20  3.436 -0.203  -0.203   -0.141   -0.141
62   PT =~ V21  1.930 -0.119  -0.119   -0.088   -0.088
63   EC =~  V1  2.273 -0.190  -0.190   -0.126   -0.126
64   EC =~  V2  0.134 -0.051  -0.051   -0.035   -0.035
65   EC =~  V3  2.081  0.162   0.162    0.125    0.125
66   EC =~  V4  0.362  0.063   0.063    0.055    0.055
67   EC =~  V5  1.260 -0.176  -0.176   -0.110   -0.110
68   EC =~  V6  2.027 -0.135  -0.135   -0.125   -0.125
69   EC =~  V7  2.052  0.163   0.163    0.120    0.120
70   EC =~ V15 11.744  0.431   0.431    0.270    0.270
71   EC =~ V16  8.363  0.353   0.353    0.214    0.214
72   EC =~ V17  1.819  0.133   0.133    0.093    0.093
73   EC =~ V18  3.119 -0.157  -0.157   -0.119   -0.119
74   EC =~ V19  0.114  0.037   0.037    0.024    0.024
75   EC =~ V20  0.003  0.006   0.006    0.004    0.004
76   EC =~ V21 12.528 -0.299  -0.299   -0.222   -0.222
77   PD =~  V1  0.036  0.021   0.021    0.014    0.014
78   PD =~  V2  0.597 -0.094  -0.094   -0.065   -0.065
79   PD =~  V3  1.654  0.125   0.125    0.097    0.097
80   PD =~  V4  0.940 -0.088  -0.088   -0.077   -0.077
81   PD =~  V5  0.210 -0.063  -0.063   -0.040   -0.040
82   PD =~  V6  1.660 -0.107  -0.107   -0.099   -0.099
83   PD =~  V7  0.559  0.073   0.073    0.054    0.054
84   PD =~  V8  4.612 -0.162  -0.162   -0.172   -0.172
85   PD =~  V9  2.497 -0.160  -0.160   -0.127   -0.127
86   PD =~ V10  0.663 -0.069  -0.069   -0.058   -0.058
87   PD =~ V11  7.314  0.243   0.243    0.196    0.196
88   PD =~ V12  0.016 -0.014  -0.014   -0.010   -0.010
89   PD =~ V13  0.247 -0.043  -0.043   -0.034   -0.034
90   PD =~ V14  1.768  0.110   0.110    0.098    0.098
91   V1 ~~  V2  1.334  0.165   0.165    0.075    0.075
92   V1 ~~  V3  0.626 -0.102  -0.102   -0.052   -0.052
93   V1 ~~  V4  2.388 -0.172  -0.172   -0.100   -0.100
94   V1 ~~  V5  0.006  0.013   0.013    0.005    0.005
95   V1 ~~  V6  1.367  0.124   0.124    0.076    0.076
96   V1 ~~  V7  1.190  0.158   0.158    0.077    0.077
97   V1 ~~  V8  0.472 -0.057  -0.057   -0.040   -0.040
98   V1 ~~  V9  0.155  0.044   0.044    0.023    0.023
99   V1 ~~ V10  3.159 -0.161  -0.161   -0.090   -0.090
100  V1 ~~ V11  0.995 -0.097  -0.097   -0.052   -0.052
101  V1 ~~ V12  0.042  0.025   0.025    0.011    0.011
102  V1 ~~ V13  0.443  0.062   0.062    0.033    0.033
103  V1 ~~ V14  0.196  0.040   0.040    0.023    0.023
104  V1 ~~ V15  0.753  0.116   0.116    0.048    0.048
105  V1 ~~ V16  0.977  0.128   0.128    0.052    0.052
106  V1 ~~ V17  1.960  0.146   0.146    0.067    0.067
107  V1 ~~ V18  4.543 -0.200  -0.200   -0.100   -0.100
108  V1 ~~ V19  0.337 -0.067  -0.067   -0.029   -0.029
109  V1 ~~ V20  0.279  0.061   0.061    0.028    0.028
110  V1 ~~ V21  0.001 -0.002  -0.002   -0.001   -0.001
111  V2 ~~  V3  0.687 -0.105  -0.105   -0.056   -0.056
112  V2 ~~  V4  0.024 -0.018  -0.018   -0.011   -0.011
113  V2 ~~  V5  0.270  0.092   0.092    0.040    0.040
114  V2 ~~  V6  2.780  0.179   0.179    0.115    0.115
115  V2 ~~  V7  2.893 -0.219  -0.219   -0.111   -0.111
116  V2 ~~  V8  2.139 -0.141  -0.141   -0.103   -0.103
117  V2 ~~  V9  0.015 -0.016  -0.016   -0.009   -0.009
118  V2 ~~ V10  0.394 -0.066  -0.066   -0.038   -0.038
119  V2 ~~ V11  0.000  0.000   0.000    0.000    0.000
120  V2 ~~ V12  1.149  0.152   0.152    0.070    0.070
121  V2 ~~ V13  0.014  0.013   0.013    0.007    0.007
122  V2 ~~ V14  0.104  0.034   0.034    0.021    0.021
123  V2 ~~ V15  0.502 -0.111  -0.111   -0.048   -0.048
124  V2 ~~ V16  0.308  0.084   0.084    0.035    0.035
125  V2 ~~ V17  5.378 -0.281  -0.281   -0.136   -0.136
126  V2 ~~ V18  0.407 -0.070  -0.070   -0.036   -0.036
127  V2 ~~ V19  2.946  0.232   0.232    0.105    0.105
128  V2 ~~ V20  0.880  0.126   0.126    0.060    0.060
129  V2 ~~ V21  0.000  0.001   0.001    0.001    0.001
130  V3 ~~  V4  0.125  0.034   0.034    0.023    0.023
131  V3 ~~  V5  0.313  0.080   0.080    0.039    0.039
132  V3 ~~  V6  2.096 -0.131  -0.131   -0.093   -0.093
133  V3 ~~  V7  2.094  0.168   0.168    0.095    0.095
134  V3 ~~  V8  0.148  0.029   0.029    0.024    0.024
135  V3 ~~  V9  7.041  0.270   0.270    0.165    0.165
136  V3 ~~ V10  4.964  0.185   0.185    0.120    0.120
137  V3 ~~ V11  0.572 -0.067  -0.067   -0.042   -0.042
138  V3 ~~ V12  5.103 -0.253  -0.253   -0.130   -0.130
139  V3 ~~ V13  0.034 -0.016  -0.016   -0.010   -0.010
140  V3 ~~ V14  0.011  0.009   0.009    0.006    0.006
141  V3 ~~ V15  0.151 -0.048  -0.048   -0.023   -0.023
142  V3 ~~ V16  0.722  0.101   0.101    0.047    0.047
143  V3 ~~ V17  0.003  0.005   0.005    0.003    0.003
144  V3 ~~ V18  0.026  0.014   0.014    0.008    0.008
145  V3 ~~ V19  0.213  0.049   0.049    0.025    0.025
146  V3 ~~ V20  0.203 -0.048  -0.048   -0.025   -0.025
147  V3 ~~ V21  0.078  0.023   0.023    0.013    0.013
148  V4 ~~  V5  0.227 -0.063  -0.063   -0.035   -0.035
149  V4 ~~  V6  4.605  0.176   0.176    0.142    0.142
150  V4 ~~  V7  0.416 -0.065  -0.065   -0.042   -0.042
151  V4 ~~  V8  8.460  0.208   0.208    0.193    0.193
152  V4 ~~  V9  1.849  0.130   0.130    0.091    0.091
153  V4 ~~ V10  0.353  0.047   0.047    0.034    0.034
154  V4 ~~ V11  0.031 -0.015  -0.015   -0.010   -0.010
155  V4 ~~ V12  5.761 -0.254  -0.254   -0.148   -0.148
156  V4 ~~ V13  2.375 -0.123  -0.123   -0.086   -0.086
157  V4 ~~ V14  2.936  0.133   0.133    0.103    0.103
158  V4 ~~ V15  0.001 -0.004  -0.004   -0.002   -0.002
159  V4 ~~ V16  0.081  0.032   0.032    0.017    0.017
160  V4 ~~ V17  0.819  0.082   0.082    0.050    0.050
161  V4 ~~ V18  2.196  0.121   0.121    0.080    0.080
162  V4 ~~ V19  8.141 -0.287  -0.287   -0.164   -0.164
163  V4 ~~ V20  2.814 -0.168  -0.168   -0.101   -0.101
164  V4 ~~ V21  0.013  0.009   0.009    0.006    0.006
165  V5 ~~  V6  0.521  0.087   0.087    0.051    0.051
166  V5 ~~  V7  0.333 -0.082  -0.082   -0.038   -0.038
167  V5 ~~  V8  0.489 -0.076  -0.076   -0.051   -0.051
168  V5 ~~  V9  0.784 -0.130  -0.130   -0.065   -0.065
169  V5 ~~ V10  1.440 -0.143  -0.143   -0.076   -0.076
170  V5 ~~ V11  0.545  0.094   0.094    0.048    0.048
171  V5 ~~ V12  2.527  0.256   0.256    0.107    0.107
172  V5 ~~ V13  0.190  0.053   0.053    0.027    0.027
173  V5 ~~ V14  2.859 -0.200  -0.200   -0.111   -0.111
174  V5 ~~ V15  0.898 -0.168  -0.168   -0.066   -0.066
175  V5 ~~ V16  5.360 -0.397  -0.397   -0.151   -0.151
176  V5 ~~ V17  1.636  0.176   0.176    0.077    0.077
177  V5 ~~ V18  0.480  0.086   0.086    0.041    0.041
178  V5 ~~ V19  0.399 -0.097  -0.097   -0.040   -0.040
179  V5 ~~ V20  1.411  0.181   0.181    0.079    0.079
180  V5 ~~ V21  0.026 -0.019  -0.019   -0.009   -0.009
181  V6 ~~  V7  3.178 -0.170  -0.170   -0.116   -0.116
182  V6 ~~  V8  5.423  0.150   0.150    0.148    0.148
183  V6 ~~  V9  0.050  0.019   0.019    0.014    0.014
184  V6 ~~ V10  0.083 -0.020  -0.020   -0.016   -0.016
185  V6 ~~ V11  0.214 -0.035  -0.035   -0.026   -0.026
186  V6 ~~ V12  0.122 -0.033  -0.033   -0.021   -0.021
187  V6 ~~ V13  0.000 -0.001  -0.001   -0.001   -0.001
188  V6 ~~ V14  4.327 -0.146  -0.146   -0.120   -0.120
189  V6 ~~ V15  0.818 -0.095  -0.095   -0.055   -0.055
190  V6 ~~ V16  0.625 -0.080  -0.080   -0.045   -0.045
191  V6 ~~ V17  0.109 -0.027  -0.027   -0.017   -0.017
192  V6 ~~ V18  0.432 -0.048  -0.048   -0.034   -0.034
193  V6 ~~ V19  4.112  0.184   0.184    0.112    0.112
194  V6 ~~ V20  0.572 -0.068  -0.068   -0.044   -0.044
195  V6 ~~ V21  0.003 -0.004  -0.004   -0.003   -0.003
196  V7 ~~  V8  0.055  0.018   0.018    0.014    0.014
197  V7 ~~  V9  2.505 -0.158  -0.158   -0.092   -0.092
198  V7 ~~ V10  0.007 -0.007  -0.007   -0.004   -0.004
199  V7 ~~ V11  4.207  0.179   0.179    0.107    0.107
200  V7 ~~ V12  1.416  0.131   0.131    0.064    0.064
201  V7 ~~ V13  0.200 -0.037  -0.037   -0.022   -0.022
202  V7 ~~ V14  0.025 -0.013  -0.013   -0.008   -0.008
203  V7 ~~ V15  6.069  0.298   0.298    0.137    0.137
204  V7 ~~ V16  0.649 -0.094  -0.094   -0.042   -0.042
205  V7 ~~ V17  2.628  0.152   0.152    0.078    0.078
206  V7 ~~ V18  0.003  0.004   0.004    0.002    0.002
207  V7 ~~ V19  0.704 -0.088  -0.088   -0.042   -0.042
208  V7 ~~ V20  1.795 -0.139  -0.139   -0.071   -0.071
209  V7 ~~ V21  0.048 -0.017  -0.017   -0.009   -0.009
210  V8 ~~  V9 12.280  0.284   0.284    0.239    0.239
211  V8 ~~ V10  3.208  0.123   0.123    0.109    0.109
212  V8 ~~ V11  3.373 -0.133  -0.133   -0.114   -0.114
213  V8 ~~ V12  2.443 -0.141  -0.141   -0.100   -0.100
214  V8 ~~ V13  1.238 -0.079  -0.079   -0.067   -0.067
215  V8 ~~ V14  0.333 -0.039  -0.039   -0.036   -0.036
216  V8 ~~ V15  0.161 -0.039  -0.039   -0.026   -0.026
217  V8 ~~ V16  2.139  0.137   0.137    0.088    0.088
218  V8 ~~ V17  1.608  0.095   0.095    0.070    0.070
219  V8 ~~ V18  0.018  0.009   0.009    0.007    0.007
220  V8 ~~ V19  0.006  0.006   0.006    0.004    0.004
221  V8 ~~ V20 12.260 -0.290  -0.290   -0.213   -0.213
222  V8 ~~ V21  1.544 -0.079  -0.079   -0.062   -0.062
223  V9 ~~ V10  2.613  0.148   0.148    0.099    0.099
224  V9 ~~ V11  1.397 -0.115  -0.115   -0.074   -0.074
225  V9 ~~ V12  4.815 -0.266  -0.266   -0.141   -0.141
226  V9 ~~ V13  1.746 -0.126  -0.126   -0.079   -0.079
227  V9 ~~ V14  0.005  0.007   0.007    0.005    0.005
228  V9 ~~ V15  2.594 -0.209  -0.209   -0.104   -0.104
229  V9 ~~ V16  0.996  0.125   0.125    0.060    0.060
230  V9 ~~ V17  0.187 -0.043  -0.043   -0.024   -0.024
231  V9 ~~ V18  0.568  0.068   0.068    0.041    0.041
232  V9 ~~ V19  0.512 -0.080  -0.080   -0.042   -0.042
233  V9 ~~ V20  0.010  0.011   0.011    0.006    0.006
234  V9 ~~ V21  0.598 -0.066  -0.066   -0.039   -0.039
235 V10 ~~ V11  0.010 -0.009  -0.009   -0.006   -0.006
236 V10 ~~ V12  7.335 -0.284  -0.284   -0.160   -0.160
237 V10 ~~ V13  0.399 -0.055  -0.055   -0.037   -0.037
238 V10 ~~ V14  1.720  0.103   0.103    0.077    0.077
239 V10 ~~ V15  1.871 -0.144  -0.144   -0.076   -0.076
240 V10 ~~ V16  4.659  0.220   0.220    0.113    0.113
241 V10 ~~ V17  0.228 -0.039  -0.039   -0.023   -0.023
242 V10 ~~ V18  3.534  0.139   0.139    0.088    0.088
243 V10 ~~ V19  0.114 -0.031  -0.031   -0.017   -0.017
244 V10 ~~ V20  0.041 -0.018  -0.018   -0.011   -0.011
245 V10 ~~ V21  4.699 -0.151  -0.151   -0.094   -0.094
246 V11 ~~ V12  3.274  0.200   0.200    0.108    0.108
247 V11 ~~ V13  1.027 -0.092  -0.092   -0.059   -0.059
248 V11 ~~ V14  1.574  0.104   0.104    0.074    0.074
249 V11 ~~ V15  0.897  0.107   0.107    0.054    0.054
250 V11 ~~ V16  0.751  0.095   0.095    0.047    0.047
251 V11 ~~ V17  0.175  0.037   0.037    0.021    0.021
252 V11 ~~ V18  3.258 -0.143  -0.143   -0.087   -0.087
253 V11 ~~ V19  4.419  0.206   0.206    0.109    0.109
254 V11 ~~ V20  0.015  0.012   0.012    0.007    0.007
255 V11 ~~ V21  0.433  0.049   0.049    0.029    0.029
256 V12 ~~ V13 24.941  0.550   0.550    0.292    0.292
257 V12 ~~ V14  2.429 -0.159  -0.159   -0.094   -0.094
258 V12 ~~ V15  1.615  0.181   0.181    0.076    0.076
259 V12 ~~ V16  2.658 -0.225  -0.225   -0.091   -0.091
260 V12 ~~ V17  0.418 -0.072  -0.072   -0.033   -0.033
261 V12 ~~ V18  2.365 -0.154  -0.154   -0.077   -0.077
262 V12 ~~ V19  0.053  0.028   0.028    0.012    0.012
263 V12 ~~ V20  3.335  0.224   0.224    0.103    0.103
264 V12 ~~ V21  0.525  0.068   0.068    0.034    0.034
265 V13 ~~ V14  0.634 -0.066  -0.066   -0.046   -0.046
266 V13 ~~ V15  1.591  0.136   0.136    0.068    0.068
267 V13 ~~ V16  0.093 -0.032  -0.032   -0.015   -0.015
268 V13 ~~ V17  0.419  0.054   0.054    0.030    0.030
269 V13 ~~ V18  2.006 -0.107  -0.107   -0.064   -0.064
270 V13 ~~ V19  0.558 -0.070  -0.070   -0.036   -0.036
271 V13 ~~ V20  3.600  0.176   0.176    0.097    0.097
272 V13 ~~ V21  0.690 -0.059  -0.059   -0.035   -0.035
273 V14 ~~ V15  5.439  0.245   0.245    0.136    0.136
274 V14 ~~ V16  0.043  0.021   0.021    0.011    0.011
275 V14 ~~ V17  0.124 -0.029  -0.029   -0.018   -0.018
276 V14 ~~ V18  1.084  0.077   0.077    0.051    0.051
277 V14 ~~ V19  0.003  0.005   0.005    0.003    0.003
278 V14 ~~ V20  0.400 -0.057  -0.057   -0.035   -0.035
279 V14 ~~ V21  0.331 -0.040  -0.040   -0.026   -0.026
280 V15 ~~ V16  9.175  0.471   0.471    0.179    0.179
281 V15 ~~ V17 14.822  0.487   0.487    0.213    0.213
282 V15 ~~ V18  7.672 -0.318  -0.318   -0.150   -0.150
283 V15 ~~ V19  0.884 -0.131  -0.131   -0.054   -0.054
284 V15 ~~ V20  0.194 -0.061  -0.061   -0.026   -0.026
285 V15 ~~ V21  3.977 -0.222  -0.222   -0.103   -0.103
286 V16 ~~ V17  4.127  0.253   0.253    0.107    0.107
287 V16 ~~ V18  1.316 -0.130  -0.130   -0.060   -0.060
288 V16 ~~ V19  3.332  0.251   0.251    0.099    0.099
289 V16 ~~ V20  3.795 -0.263  -0.263   -0.110   -0.110
290 V16 ~~ V21  7.409 -0.304  -0.304   -0.136   -0.136
291 V17 ~~ V18  0.160  0.038   0.038    0.020    0.020
292 V17 ~~ V19  0.582 -0.086  -0.086   -0.039   -0.039
293 V17 ~~ V20  2.825 -0.185  -0.185   -0.090   -0.090
294 V17 ~~ V21  4.905 -0.211  -0.211   -0.109   -0.109
295 V18 ~~ V19  0.272 -0.054  -0.054   -0.027   -0.027
296 V18 ~~ V20  0.001  0.004   0.004    0.002    0.002
297 V18 ~~ V21  6.618  0.227   0.227    0.127    0.127
298 V19 ~~ V20  0.866 -0.113  -0.113   -0.051   -0.051
299 V19 ~~ V21  0.808  0.092   0.092    0.045    0.045
300 V20 ~~ V21 12.178  0.343   0.343    0.176    0.176
```

Comment: not sure but all the examples in the documentation are similar

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question! If I'm correct, the previous version of lavaan printed out modification indices for all possible model paths, but the specified paths had 0.000 indices values. The newer version of lavaan just omits all of the paths that have been already specified by the model, and prints the output from the line where the indices value is different from 0.000 (in this case, it's line 49).

I hope that's correct, but please feel free to correct me if it's not.

Comment: somehow when i run modification indices i don't see any variances (i'm trying to find partial invariance for error variances

Comment: @BenjaminTelkamp not sure if you are still experiencing this problem, but would you mind sharing your code and /or sample?

Comment: Hi, i fixed my problem: modificationIndices(model, free.remove = FALSE). or you needed something else?